# Cocoa Bindings Model Key Path Division

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

In my project I have two text fields which are bound to a mutable dictionary. I want to make a third text field that is the first field divided by the second. However when I try to do this inside the Model Key Path in the bindings tab in Interface Builder it says it is invalid. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform arbitrary arithmetic operations or use arbitrary expressions in a key or key path. A key specifies a property provided by an object, and a key path specifies a sequence of properties. Although there are some variations such as collection operators, they do not apply to your particular setting.

That said, you could try:

- Using a custom class instead of a dictionary and exposing a property that represents the arithmetic operation based on those two other properties. The [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE) has a section on that.
- Using a custom [value transformer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/ValueTransformers.html) that would transform the dictionary into the result of the arithmetic operation.
- Using a category on `NSDictionary` to expose a property representing the arithmetic operation. I personally think this is overkill and wouldn’t really recommend it.
- Not using bindings at all and performing the arithmetic operation directly in your application delegate, window controller, or view controller.